# Wordpress arguments to filter WP query

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I'm currently grabbing some posts using SQL. I am wanting to use some arguments in the posts I have grabbed. Is this possible? I'm trying to limit the amount of posts returned per page to paginate it. I usually use the args array. Can the args array work with this?

```
$get_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'job_listing'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can, you just need to get the `ID`s from the database in a flat array, but you don't really need to query the database directly.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'job_listing',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged'          => get_query_var('paged', 1),
  'post__in'       => $get_posts,
);
```

Complete [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)